# Perl: passing two argument through a config file

Tags: perl

What should I do if I have to pass two values for same variable? Does following syntax work ?

```
sub get_db { return "database_name", "new_database"};
```

It does not pass both the value

Comment: I guess you'll need an array.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to return several values from a sub is a list: (NOTE - none of the following code has been tested)

```
return ($db_name, $new_db, $table, $rows)
...
my ($database_name, $database, $table_name, $entry_count) = get_db();
```

but that's easy to mess up - if you have a missmatch between the number of things returned and received something silently becomes undef.  Likewise if the order of returned values is wrong, you are going to introduce a subtle bug.

Slightly better is to return a hashref;

```
....
my $return_values = { NAME => $db_name ,  DB => $new_db , TABLE => $table } ;
# add the number of rows and return it
$return_values->{ COUNT } = $rows ;
return $return_values ;
...
...
my $db_stuff = get_db();
for my $i (1 .. $db_stuff->{COUNT}) {
    ...
```

Better again is to learn a little OO and return an object.  [Moo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo) is one of many options - it would look something like this:

```
Package DBstuff;

has name,  is => ro ;
has db,    is => ro ;
has table, is => ro ;
has count, is => rw ;

1;

... in another file ...

my $db_stuff = DBstuff->new(
                  name => $name ,
                    db => $db   ,
                 table => $table,
               );
# Add rows and return
$db_stuff->count( $rows );
return $db_stuff ;
...
...
my $db_data = get_db();
for my $i (1 .. $db_data->count) {
    ...
```

There is also a module called Object::Result which would almost certainly be overkill but whether you use it or not, I'd like to recommend the [RATIONAL section](https://metacpan.org/pod/Object::Result#RATIONALE) of that module's documentation which covers the issue of returning several things from a sub in more depth.

Answer (score 0):

Perl allows to return an array with multiple values, e.g.

```
sub get_db { return ["database_name", "new_database"] };
```